# Active function keys for visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, step-into

In visual studio 2013,the Step Into function key(F11) doesn't work and it just works for laptop.

For example when i am in visual studio and debug program and press F11 it works for brightness of system and doesn't work for Step Into.

How can i active it for Step Into?

Comment: Try Fn+F11 combination

Comment: Thanks,it works.But is it a way to active function keys just for visual studio and doesn't work for system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this key combination `Fn+F11`